# Android Twitter login pop up is not appearing when using Parsetwitterutils

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform

```
ParseTwitterUtils.initialize(TWITTER_KEY,TWITTER_SECRET);
LogInCallback callback = new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
                    }
                }
            };
            ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this,callback);
```

Hi I used above code to call twitter from my app but in always result that user is null. I initialized it properly with valid keys,I don't know why it doesn't make me to authentication screen.Can someone help me please?

Comment: Use Fabric plugin to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you Ashish now I used fabric as like you said but after I closed the app twitter automatically log out from app. Do you have any idea how to prevent log out.

Comment: May be this can help you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443704/parse-android-getcurrentuser-objectid-is-null-after-twitter-login . Make sure if your app is configured properly ..